# Timeout error after adding untrackOutstandingTimeouts:true in protractor conf

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, timeout, protractor

My protractor conf looks like this:

```
    exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: "../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.51.0.jar",
    seleniumPort: 4444,
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    specs: specs,
    untrackOutstandingTimeouts:true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000
  },

  framework: "jasmine2"
}
```

I am trying perform action on angular page but fails with error -

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 150 seconds. 
Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. 
The following tasks were pending:
- $http: /api/v1/query/tail/242ac110002-8/1h?t=1456925874600
```

I have added **untrackOutstandingTimeouts:true** in protractor conf, still I am getting above error.

```
Protractor Version - 3.1.1
Node version - 4.3.1
Selenium-webdriver - 2.51.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: untrackOutstandingTimeouts:true is for $timeout and I am getting error for $http. How can I handle for $http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to solve above problem using browser.ignoreSynchronization

```
browser.get('/');
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;

//Go to page where $http  and $timeout is added
//Perform any action, steps here

browser.sleep(5000); //This can be replace with wait condition

browser.ignoresynchronization=false
```